# As i m using SSO, i want user specific session id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i m using SSO , act when user is getting signd out from portal then all other sessions od same user on different portal should be expired as it is SSO. plz help i m using Rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

One implementation is with http://code.google.com/p/rubycas-server/